# Accees Application URL without Context root

Tags: apache, tomcat, jboss7.x

Am using Apache infront of Jboss App server. My application "Test" is deployed in Jboss and apache is mounted to Jboss with mod_jk. I access my application as example https://example.com/Test
evrything works fine.
But my current requirment it to access the application by URL example https://example.com/, i dont want to use context root. 
Please suggest me how to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

For a WAR you'd need to use a `jboss-web.xml`. For an EAR you could use the `application.xml`.

The `jboss-web.xml` would look something like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
   <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

You can read more details at http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/jbosswebserver/how-to-deploy-a-web-application-on-the-root-context-on-jboss-as-7.